# Securely decode NSArray with elements conforming to a protocol (NSSecureCoding)

Tags: objective-c

When securely decoding a property (e.g. `records`) of type `NSArray` you would usually do this:

```
[decoder decodeObjectOfClasses:[NSSet setWithObjects:[NSArray class], [ClassOfElementsInArray class], nil] forKey:@"records"];
```

But how would you decode `records`, if all the base class knows is that the elements in `records` conform to a protocol `<RecordEntity>`? Are there any best practices?

---

**Update**

I've tested [@DBoyer's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31503003/480069) using lightweight generics `[NSArray<id<RecordEntity>> class]` but unfortunately this doesn't work. When decoding, the `NSKeyedUnarchiver` throws the following exception saying that only objects of type `NSArray` are expected.

```
-[BaseClassTest testDecode] : failed: caught "NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException", "value for key 'NS.objects' was of unexpected class 'Record'. 
Allowed classes are '{(NSArray)}'."
```

Comment: Generics are generally a compile time feature. Only at compile time the compiler knows about generic types and can check them for correct usage. At run time, `NSArray<whatever>` is just `NSArray` and secure decoding happens at run time. As of today, one exception is if you mix Obj-C with Swift code. In that case generics are remembered for the Swift runtime but are not used in Obj-C code either.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight-forwarded way. `Class` is a pointer to a class, not to a protocol. Even protocols are similar to classes inside the RTE, a `-isKindOfClass:` would not return `YES`, if the found class implements the protocol.

You can do two things:

1. Write a method `-decodeArrayOfItemsConformingToProtocol:forKey:`. Use the existing decode-methods as a template. I never have done this, but I think that it is more than an one-hour-job.
2. Use the RTE to find out, which classes conform to the protocol and take this as a list of the allowed classes.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Xcode 7 the advancements in objective-C make this possible using the new "light weight generics" feature:

```
[decoder decodeObjectOfClass:[NSArray<id<RecordEntity>> class] forKey:@"records"];
```

Note: This will compile totally fine, but I have not tested to make sure it read and write to disk perfectly. This would be a good place to start though.

Comment: Yeah ... but this is not backwards compatible, right?

Comment: I don't know that for sure but I don't see why not as the version of the compiler shouldn't have any affect on the version of iOS that it can target. I have code using light-weight generics running totally fine on an iOS7 simulator

Comment: @DBoyer There are two possibilities: 1. If it is a compile-time feature only, it wouldn't work if you change the class in the data stream because this has to be checked at runtime. Meaningless. 2. If it works at runtime, the version of the runtime can have affect. (I guess it is 1, but I did not test it.)

Comment: I've updated my answer with test results to your suggestion.

Comment: This doesn't work at all. I would suggest removing the answer.