# NSSecureCoding with Array of Conforming Elements in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, core-data, appkit

I have a class conforming to `NSManagedObject` with three `@NSManaged` properties:
They have the following types `Core Data Type : Swift Type`:

- `String : String`
- `Boolean : Bool`
- `Transformable : [NSColor]`

With the following class:

```
public class MyClass: NSManagedObject {
  @NSManaged private(set) var text: String
  @NSManaged private(set) var myBool: Bool
  @NSManaged private(set) var colors: [NSColor]
  
  // ... other code ...
}
```

Currently I get the following warning:

> CoreData: One or more models in this application are using
> transformable properties with transformer names that are either unset,
> or set to NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName. Please switch to
> using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" or a subclass of
> NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer instead. At some point, Core Data
> will default to using "NSSecureUnarchiveFromData" when nil is
> specified, and transformable properties containing classes that do not
> support NSSecureCoding will become unreadable.

The error is raised in this part of the code:

```
func fetchPalettes() -> [MyClass] {
  let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<MyClass>.init(entityName: "MyClass")
  let result = try? self.moc.fetch(fetchRequest) // <<-------
  return result ?? []
}
```

Obviously this problem is not a new one and I have looked at a few resources like [these](https://danielbernal.co/coredata-transformable-and-nssecurecoding-in-ios-13/) [two](https://www.kairadiagne.com/2020/01/13/nssecurecoding-and-transformable-properties-in-core-data.html).

But as far as I understand all the resources I stumbled upon, a class is required if an attribute wants to securely conform to the `Core Data Transformable` type.
If I understand it correctly one can do two things:

- Make **the class** conform to `NSSecureCoding` by calling `decodeObject(of: Class, for: Key)` during initialisation in `init?(coder: NSCoder)` and implementing `encode(with coder: NSCoder)`
- or implement an `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer`, which needs to override `allowedTopLevelClasses: [AnyClass]` in order to be called and thus also requires the object to be **a class** (returning `Array<NSColor>.self` gives an error in Swift)

I want to prevent wrapping the `NSColor` property in a class because it would have other repercussions and I would consider it bloated code. I have tried the later of the two options listed above.

Shouldn't it be possible to use an array of `NSSecureCoding` conforming elements? Am I not seeing a solution? Is there any way to encode/decode `[NSColor]` securely?

(I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31502931/securely-decode-nsarray-with-elements-conforming-to-a-protocol-nssecurecoding) and I don't think its related)

———————— EDIT ————————————————————

I will now kind of answer my own question, but since I am not 100% sure if this it is correct I will do this in the question.

I have tried using other types like `[NSString]` and `[String]` with core data in a different project and that seems to work flawlessly. I have also tried using [`NSColorList`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolorlist) instead of `[NSColor]` but doing so I ran into the same kind of problem. It doesn't even work with [`NSColor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolor). Even tho both (`NSColor` and `NSColorList`) are said to conform to `NSSecureCoding` (according to their documentation) both types seem not to implement this protocol correctly.

**To answer my question:**

Generally it seems that using an array of a type conforming to `NSSecureCoding` like `[String]` or `[NSString]` seems to work out of the box. (The properties needs to be of the core data type `Transformable` and *Transformer* needs to be set to `NSSecureUnarchiveFromData` in the *Attribute Inspector* for the given attribute)

Just in my personal case of `NSColor`, `[NSColor]` or `NSColorList` do not seem to conform to `NSSecureCoding` correctly. **Correct me if I am wrong!**

I have solved this by using `[String]` instead of `[NSColor]` as the `@NSManaged` property. I therefore save a hex representation string instead of the object. I use a computed var in order to make `[NSColor]` public.

Hope this helps someone at some point.